# Accessing 2 different private git repos with a single SSH key during a CI / CD workflow in bitrise

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, bitrise

I have 2 repos which I am using in my CI / CD pipeline using bitrise. For setting up bitrise with one git repo is quite simple and straight forward which builds my 1st repo fine post which I need to push the .xcframework file created from step1 into a different private repo, while doing so I get below error which is because my git is not authenticated to use different repo at this point.

Error :

```
ERROR: The key you are authenticating with has been marked as read only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any solutions or approaches, Please help.

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the same approach as it is in case of [submodules](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/faq/adding-projects-with-submodules/). Then you are not adding SSH key to the project as a deploy keys, but add it to your or machine github account as a SSH.